# Arrow keys don't seem to work?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to make a maze game however this is the only code I can't seem to get to work. I want the picture box (the player) to move in the direction of the arrow keys.
I have tried this code:

```
Private Sub BLevel1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = 37 Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Left = PictureBoxPlayer.Left - 10
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = 38 Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Top = PictureBoxPlayer.Top - 10
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = 39 Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Left = PictureBoxPlayer.Left + 10
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = 40 Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Top = PictureBoxPlayer.Top + 10
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried location codes but the arrow keys don't seem to move the picture box. This is the only issue I am running into.
Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Why aren't you using Keys enumeration as in this example ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 3):

The cursor keys are special, they are used to navigate the focus from one control to another.  So they are normally intercepted before they get to the control that currently has the focus.  Furthermore, you wrote a KeyDown event for the form, it won't have the focus when the form has other controls so won't get the KeyDown event.  It is unclear whether that applies here.

The best way to go about it is to intercept the cursor keys yourself, before they can be used elsewhere.  You do so by writing an override for the form's ProcessCmdKey() method, like this:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Left Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Left = Math.Max(0, PictureBoxPlayer.Left - 10)
        Return True
    ElseIf keyData = Keys.Right Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Left = Math.Min(Me.ClientSize.Width - PictureBoxPlayer.Width, PictureBoxPlayer.Left + 10)
        Return True
    ElseIf keyData = Keys.Up Then
        '' etc..
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

I threw in the code to prevent the user from moving the player outside of the form.  Finish the code by writing the Keys.Up and Keys.Down code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use Listbox1, make an image array and bring the listbox1 to back so it cant be seen, then addrange the listbox1 from the Folder Path of the image folder, It seems like simple image viewer.

You can try this

use the button or anything with click method

```
    Dim myimg As Array
Private Sub img_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        myimg = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myimg)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Then set the tab index to 1 on the listbox
then click twice the listbox1 and insert this

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.Refresh()
    Me.BackgroundImage = Nothing
    Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

Use your arrow key, image will automatically change.
You can change Me to Picturebox.
Hope it helps